# LOGICALLY EQUIVALENT: NAND and NOR

Tags: logic

Is there a way to represent "p NOR q" using "NAND" with logical equivalence?

Comment: Do you know how to express negation with with NAND?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$(p \operatorname{NOR} q) \equiv (\neg p \land \neg q),
$$
so that
$$
\neg p \equiv (p \operatorname{NOR} p)
$$
and therefore
$$
(p \land q) \equiv (\neg p \operatorname{NOR} \neg q).
$$

Now, $\operatorname{NAND}$ is defined as:
$$\begin{align}
(p \operatorname{NAND} q) &\equiv \neg(p \land q),
\end{align}$$
so by the above, it's clear how to express it using $\operatorname{NOR}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:
$\begin{array}{l:c:l}
1. & A\bar\vee B = \neg(A\vee B) & \bar\vee \textsf{ is nor}
\\ 2. & (A\vee B)= \neg(\neg A\wedge \neg B) & \textsf{by deMorgan's Law}
\\ 3. & A\barwedge B = \neg(A\wedge B) & \barwedge \textsf{ is nand} 
\\ 4. & \neg A = A\barwedge A & = A\bar\vee A \textsf{ also}
\end{array}$